# Multiple inline comparison while assigning values to object properties

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.0

I am working on c# data model class, I created instance and assigning values from another object. I am aware of single line comparision but I need multiple, I have tried && operator but compiler complain 'invalid opperator'. I am sure what I am missing, surly it must be simple!

```
var answerDataModel = new AnswerDataModel()
        {
            Id = answerId,
           //need help to 
            Value = AnswerDtoObject.Answers.FirstOrDefault() == null? && 
                    isSubQuestionExist == true ? "_SBQA" 
                    : AnswerDtoObject.Answers.FirstOrDefault(),

        };
```

if I remove "&& isSubQuestionExist == true ?", then code works

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Value = (AnswerDtoObject.Answers.FirstOrDefault() == null) && 
                (isSubQuestionExist == true) ? "_SBQA" 
                : AnswerDtoObject.Answers.FirstOrDefault(),
```

Answer (score 4):

You have an errant `?` operator.  Just combine your comparisons in a single conditional operator:

```
Value = (AnswerDtoObject.Answers.FirstOrDefault() == null && isSubQuestionExist == true) ?
  "_SBQA" :
  AnswerDtoObject.Answers.FirstOrDefault()
```